Why does Jaccard Score differ between batch summation and single run calculations?
I encountered an issue with the jaccard_score function (jaccard_score(ground_true, inference, average="micro", zero_division=0)).
I don't have enough memory to store all the ground_truth and inferences of my validation. Therefore, what I'm doing is summing the Jaccard score of each batch to a variable, and at the end of the validation, I divide this variable by the number of batches. With this approach, I obtain a result of 0.8084487056909495.
However, when I use a computer with a larger capacity to process the data, and process all the ground_truth and masks at once, I get a value like 0.7716579100568796. Could someone explain why this is happening?
